# How to mark a part of c# code to be compiled if particular library is referenced and ignored if it isn't?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I would like to build a version of an application of mine without use of some features provided by a class library but avoid deleting the actual code (the code using the feature and the corresponding `using` directive).

Normally the whole application is going to fail to be built as soon as I unreference the assembly but I would like the dependent code parts to be excluded from compilation process instead.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) to control this - not on the basis of your references, but on the basis of symbols:

```
#if USE_SOME_LIBRARY
   // Code that uses the library
#endif
```

Then just make sure that you define `USE_SOME_LIBRARY` in any build configurations where you have the reference.

Comment: Ok, but what about third-party libraries?

Comment: Can I include or exclude a library reference automatically based on build configuration too?

Comment: @Ivan: Yes, but you'll need to do it manually by editing the project file.

Comment: There is no need to exclude the project reference. If nowhere in your code uses the .dll then it wont be used.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: This *is* about third-party libraries (at least potentially) - you just define your build configurations appropriately so that you have one which refers to the library and defines the symbol, and one which doesn't.

Comment: @CathalMF: While that's true, I think I'd probably do both - that way you can be certain at compile-time that you haven't excluded some code that you *should* have excluded.